# number sequence puzzle deep six

Tags: number-sequence

Just a quick puzzle I just thought up. (so apologies if this has already been done)

Here's numbers 1 to 5 in a sequence:

> 5-4-1-3-2

I now want to add the number 6 into the sequence, but where should I place it?

What should the new number sequence be, and why?

p.s. title isn't a clue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would put it

> Between the 1 and 3 to get 5-4-1-6-3-2

Because

> Then the numbers are in alphabetical order (when written in English).

Comment: I'll have to come up with trickier puzzles !

Answer (score 2):

I would put the six inbetween

> five and four,

as the first three numbers are set up so that

> the three is put in the middle of the first two numbers, so the next three are a mirror of it.

Comment: I have edited your post so that the actual answer and a reasoning are not immediately visible, hence they will not spoil the puzzle if someone reads them unwittingly.

Comment: Good effort and I can see the logic, but @hexomino has the answer I had in mind :)